# Как сделать проверку в базе данных?

Tags: c#, sql

Как сделать так чтобы когда приходил запрос в базу данных была проверка на наличие в ней пользователя, использую SqlLite и C#. Я сделал так, но данную проверку я же не буду писать в каждом методе, да и не дело это всегда возвращать объект user) Помогите)

```
public class DataBaseCommands
{
    public static async Task AddUsers(int userId, string userName,decimal balance)
    {
        await using var db = new DBTelegramContext();
        if (!(await db.Users.AnyAsync(u => u.UserId == userId)))
        {
            User user = new User { UserId = userId, UserName = userName, Balance = balance };
            await db.Users.AddAsync(user);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Класс таблицы

```
public partial class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    public decimal GeneralPay { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Не понял, в чём ваши претензии к этому методу )

Comment: А что тут проверять? Если пользователя нет в БД, то очевидно его `Id == 0`.

Comment: @Bulson, смотри если он ещё раз захочет добавиться, то БД выкинет ошибку так как UserId Uniqe. Это БД к Телеграмм боту и если пользователь нажмёт /start, то его добавит в БД, но если он ещё раз нажмёт /start, то его уже не должно добавить. Если пользователь отправляет команду /Баланс данная команда обращается к БД и если там нет данного пользователя, то тогда ответа тоже быть не должно) Вот как-то так. Каждый раз проверять данное условие не очень есть хорошо, я просто думал найти вариант написать один раз и всё. Я думал может как-то в БД сделать, если приходит любой запрос то чекается UserID

Comment: Сама по себе информация из базы к вам в приложение попасть не сможет, запросы в любом случае придется явно/неявно делать. Другое дело что в зависимости от размера базы, с ней можно будет работать без обращений на каждый запрос, работая с данными в памяти и лишь иногда синхронизируясь с базой: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset?view=net-5.0

Comment: Вставьте код текстом.

Comment: @aepot вставил)

Comment: Метод правильный. Лучше продумать архитектуру. Я бы на вашем месте вынес все методы CRUD отдельный сервис. Дальше через DI получал сервис и использовал нужные методы.

Comment: Надо проверять наличие пользователя не в методе добавления пользователя в БД `AddUsers()` (и почему Users множ.число? вы же в методе добавляете только одного юзера), а в методе обработчике команды `/start`, нужно создать метод `GetUserById(int id)` и первым шагом в обработчике попытаться из БД получить юзера и если такого юзера нет, тогда его добавлять в БД, а иначе сразу выходить из обработчика `\start`. И я, кстати, догадываюсь о причине вашей ошибки. Вы пляшете от БД и мыслите работой с БД, а надо бы наоборот, исходить от работы сервиса, а БД всего лишь хранилище, не более того.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, непонятно, зачем в классе `User` два айдишника. Если они действительно имеют смысл, то опишите их предназначение (добавьте информацию в вопрос).
Я бы оставил только одно свойство `Id`.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    public decimal GeneralPay { get; set; }
}
```

Во-вторых, поменяем сигнатуру метода.
Он добавляет *одного* пользователя, значит название должно быть `AddUser`.
Метод `SaveChangesAsync` возвращает количество вставленных записей. Не нужно его игнорировать, лучше вернуть его из метода. Это даст возможность контролировать его работу. Меняем `Task` на `Task<int>`.
Метод `AddAsync` тоже имеет возвращаемое значение. Т. к. в данном конкретном случае оно нами никак не используется, декларируем это явно: `_ = await db.Users.AddAsync(user);` - [Discards](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards).

В-третьих, при попытке вставки записи с неуникальным ключом будет выброшено исключение. Вот его-то и нужно ловить в блоке `try-catch`. Тут возможны два варианта.

В методе не делаем реакции на возможные исключения. Просто вставляем запись:

```
public static async Task<int> AddUser(int userId, string userName, decimal balance)
{
    User user = new User { Id = userId, UserName = userName, Balance = balance };
    using var db = new DBTelegramContext();
    _ = await db.Users.AddAsync(user);
    return await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

А вызов метода оборачиваем в `try-catch`:

```
try
{
    _ = await DataBaseCommands.AddUser(1, "user1", 101);
}
catch (DbUpdateException e)
{
    // Тут реакция на ошибки
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Другой вариант. `try-catch` внутри метода:

```
public static async Task<int> AddUser(int userId, string userName, decimal balance)
{
    User user = new User { Id = userId, UserName = userName, Balance = balance };
    using var db = new DBTelegramContext();

    try
    {
        _ = await db.Users.AddAsync(user);
        return await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        // Тут реакция на ошибку: логирование и т. п.
        return 0;
    }
}
```

При этом нет нужды ловить исключение при его вызове. Хотя, в любом случае могут быть выброшены другие эксепшены, наподобие отсутствия соединения и пр.

---

В обоих случаях вам же нужно не просто подавить ошибку, а как-то проинформировать пользователя и попытаться исправить положение. Ведь это может оказаться катастрофой, что данные не вставлены и пропали.

```
int entriesWritten = await DataBaseCommands.AddUser(1, "user1", 101);
if (entriesWritten != 1) // что-то пошло не так
```

---

Самое главное: почему плохо делать ручную проверку перед вставкой?

Допустим, вот эта строка завершилась успешно, записи с таким id в таблице нет:

```
if (!(await db.Users.AnyAsync(u => u.UserId == userId)))
```

И тут в другом потоке или процессе происходит вставка в эту таблицу записи с таким же значением id. И когда дело доходит до вызова `SaveChangesAsync` в нашем потоке, то он завершится ошибкой.

То есть это очень ненадёжная проверка! С большим сожалением могу отметить, что такой способ постоянно приводят в блогах, статьях и в сотнях ответов на разных языках программирования тут, на stackoverflow.

Конечно, sqlite - принципиально однопользовательская БД и с ней нельзя работать из нескольких потоков/процессов. И поэтому с ней проверка с `if` будет работать корректно. Но лучше сразу приучить себя к правильной обработке всех возможных ошибок.

---

И ещё одно примечание.

Вызов `AnyAsync` сделает запрос к БД. Вызов `SaveChangesAsync` - ещё один запрос. Итого два. А самое дорогое в работе с базами данных - это именно отправка запросов. Следует минимизировать их количество.

Comment: Id - это первичный ключ с автоинкриментом, нужен для того, чтобы работать с БД через EF CORE
UserId - это id пользователя телеграмм через него пользователь сможет получать ответы на команды, которое будут обращаться к БД. Например: пользователь отправляет команду "Баланс" база данных находит пользователя по его UserId и отправляет значение его баланса)

Comment: `То есть это очень ненадёжная проверка!` А какая тогда надежная?

Comment: @Bulson - ловить исключение. СУБД выбросит ошибку при вставке, что транслируется в исключение в коде.

Comment: @ДмитрийСтепанов - не пишите это в комментариях. Отредактируйте вопрос.